# JavaScript. How to disable only vertical scroll?

Tags: javascript, uiscrollview, scroll

This code disable all scrolling:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

But how to disable only vertical scroll?

Comment: With css ?? overflow-y: hidden;

overflow-x: scroll;

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
yourdiv.onscroll = function(){
this.scrollTop = 0;
this.scrollLeft = 0;
}
```

of course this may still show scrollbars, best to use css

Comment: As with the css use overflow-x: hidden; aslo this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily oh! i think alos just adding the css might diable the div for vertical scrolling!